# Haskell: Why does (x:xs) match the list with only one element?

Tags: list, haskell

Given this definition of a function `f`:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = x:[]
```

I would assume that a call such as

```
f [1]
```

would not match, because the pattern `(x:xs)` only matches, if there are more elements `xs` after the `x` in the list, which is not the case for the list `[1]`. Or is it?

Comment: In Haskell [1] == 1:[]

Comment: The command `ghc -fwarn-incomplete-patterns` fails to complain about your code. Hence (x:xs) is found to match with [1]. In fact, your function f is basically the same thing as `take 1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you write `[x]`, a list with one element, this is short for `(x : [])`, or even more verbose `(:) x []`. So it is a "cons" (`(:)`) with `x` as element, and the empty list as tail.

So your function `f (x:xs)` will indeed match a list with one (or more) elements. For a list with one element, `x` will be the element, and `xs` an empty list.

> would not match, because the pattern `(x:xs)` only matches, if there are more elements `xs` after the `x` in the list, which is not the case for the list `[1]`.

No the `(x:xs)` matches with every *non-empty* list, with `x` the first element of the list, and `xs` a (possibly empty) list of remaining elements.

If you want to match only lists with for example two or more elements. You can match this with:

```
-- two or more elements
f (x1 : x2 : xs) = …
```

Here `x1` and `x2` will match the first and second item of the list respectively, and `xs` is a list that contains the remaining elements.

**EDIT**: to answer [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670986/haskell-why-does-xxs-match-the-list-with-only-one-element/58671009?noredirect=1#comment103643908_58671009):

> I wonder why my function definition does even compile in the first place, because the function type is `[Int] -> [Int]`, so if I give it the empty list, then that is not `[Int]` as a result, is it?

The empty list `[]` is one of the data constructors of the `[a]` type, so that means that `[]` has type `[] :: [a]`. It can match the type variable `a` with `Int`, and thus `[]` can have type `[] :: [Int]`.

> Second then, how to I match a list with exactly two elements? `[a, b]`?

You can match such list with:

```
f (a : b : []) = …
```

or you can match it with:

```
f [a, b] = …
```

The two are equivalent. `[a, b]` is *syntactical sugar*: it is replaced by the compiler to `(a : b : [])`, but for humans, it is of course more convenient to work with `[a, b]`.

Comment: OK. First of all I wonder why my function definition does even compile in the first place, because the function type is `[Int] -> [Int]`, so if I give it the empty list, then that is not `[Int]` as a result, is it? Second then, how to I match a list with exactly two elements? [a, b]?

Comment: @TMOTTM: (a) An empty list `[]` has type `[] :: [a]`, so it can match `a ~ Int`, and an empty list thus can be of type `[Int]`; (b) you can match it with `f [a, b] = ...` or `f (a:b:[]) = ...`, both are identical, since `[a,b]` is just *syntactical sugar* for `(a:b:[])`.

Comment: Put another way, if you don't think that `[]` can be a value of type `[Int]`, then what *is* its type?

Comment: An empty list is still a list, just like a backpack with nothing in it is still a backpack